# Converting from Spherical metric tensor to Cylindrical metric tensor

Tags: tensors, spherical-coordinates, general-relativity, cylindrical-coordinates

The spherical polar coordinate are $x^a=(r,\theta,\phi)$ and the cylindrical polar coordinates are $x'^a=(r',\theta',z')$. I have to convert from spherical metric tensor to cylindrical metric tensor. I know the equations for converting from cylindrical to spherical coordinates are

$$
\begin{split}
&r=\sqrt{r'^2+z'^2} \\
&\theta=\theta' \\
&\phi=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{z'}{\sqrt{r'^2+z'^2}}\right),
\end{split}
$$

and the spherical metric tensor is

$$
g_{ab} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^2\sin^2\theta
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Using

$$
g_{cd}'(x') = g_{ab}(x)\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x'^c}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x'^d},
$$

I can find the elements of the cylindrical metric tensor. However, when I calculate the first element of the cylindrical metric tensor I have

$$
\begin{split}
g_{11}' = g_{r'r'}' &= g_{11}(\frac{\partial r}{\partial r'})^2 + g_{22}(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r'})^2 + g_{33}(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r'})^2 \\
&= 1 \cdot (\frac{\partial r}{\partial r'})^2 + r^2 \cdot (\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r'})^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta \cdot (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r'})^2 \\
&= 1 \cdot (\frac{\partial r}{\partial r'})^2 + (r'^2+z'^2) \cdot (\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r'})^2 + (r'^2+z'^2)\sin^2\theta' (\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r'})^2 \\
&= (\frac{r'}{\sqrt{r'^2+z'^2}})^2 + (r'^2+z'^2)\sin^2\theta' (\frac{r'z'}{\sqrt{(r'^2+z'^2)^3}\sqrt{1-\frac{z'^2}{r'^2+z'2}}})^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{r'^2+z'^2}(r'^2+\sin^2\theta'z'^2).
\end{split}
$$

I am confused by the $\sin^2\theta'$. I know that the cylindrical metric tensor element is $g_{r'r'}'=1$, and it is easy to see that $\sin^2\theta'=1$ satisfied when $\theta=\pi/2$. But why $\sin^2\theta'=1$? How does $\sin^2\theta'$ disappear?

Comment: the products $\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x'^c}\frac{\partial x^b}{\partial x'^d}$ aren't 2nd derivatives

Comment: @janmarqz Yes, I agree. This was an error I made while writing the question. While solving the problem I did not take the second order derivative and I got the result I have written in the question. I have edited my question.